# Drupal block-level form submit URL?

Tags: forms

I have a form:

```
function form_search_products($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();

  $form['keyword'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#description' => 'Enter keywords (ie: Fat free milk)'
  );  

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Add item to my shopping list'
  );  

  return $form;
}
```

Simple and its loaded into a block region above product listings via:

```
function products_block_view($delta = '') {
 $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'search_form':
    {
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('form_search_products');
      break;
    }
  }
  return $block;
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to map a submit handler now as there is no menu...

My current menu looks like this:

```
function products_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['products/mycity'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,

    'title' => 'Enjoy shopping in MyCity',

    'page callback' => 'html_list_products',      
    'access arguments' => array('access products')
  );

  $items['products/autocomplete.json/%'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,

    'page callback' => 'json_list_products',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'access arguments' => array('access products')
  );

  return $items;
}
```

What or how do I add to the menu_hook above so that I can process form submissions done through the above block code???

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form submissions aren't dependent on there being a path to view/submit the form at, all you need to do is one of the following:

1. Name the submit function as `FORMNAME_submit()` and Drupal will pick it up automatically
2. Add the handler manually in the form function itself, e.g.

   ```
   $form['#submit'][] = 'my_submit_function';
   ```